# JMeter reads %3CEOF%3E from CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I use `CSV Data Set Config` in `JMeter` to provide username/password data to testsuite. In some cases it reads `%3CEOF%3E` from file instead of data. File is located in `/bin` folder.

Structure of file:

```
username1,password1
username2,password2
```

There isn't any empty lines at the end of the file.

```
Recycle on EOF: True
Stop Thread on EOF: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should not be seeing this issue normally you can work it around by putting your request under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and setting the following condition using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(!vars.get('foo').equals('<EOF>'),)}
```

Replace `foo` with the variable reference name from the CSV Data Set Config.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem and ran into a solution by accident. Although the txt had no empty lines when opened with "notepad" when I opened the same txt file using "notepad++" I found an empty line. I removed it from notepad++ and saved and the problem was solved.